# PPCG Sandbox Viewer

Tags: script, posts

### Screenshots

GIF of the viewer:

[image: GIF of viewer]

How the button looks:

[image]

The Viewer:

[image]

### About

This is a userscript for the Programming Puzzles & Code Golf sandbox. It shows you your currently sandboxed posts. It's score. Comments on your posts. This also allows you review posts, vote, and comment on sandbox posts.

The goal of this userscript is to create a quicker, better, way to manage your sandbox posts, and a review-queue–like way to review posts.

#### Download

You can install the userscript easily by installing the userscript from the [Github Page](https://github.com/vihanb/PPCG-SandboxViewer/blob/master/viewer.v2.user.js). To install userscripts, make sure you have a userscript extension such as [TamperMonkey](http://tampermonkey.net) installed

**[Click Here to Install](https://github.com/vihanb/PPCG-SandboxViewer/raw/master/viewer.v2.user.js)**

#### Platform

This should work on almost all browsers, such as Chrome, Firefox, Safari, and almost every browser TamperMonkey supports.

<sub>I haven't tested this *that* much *yet*</sub>

### Contact

I, Downgoat, created this script, if there's a bug or something else that needs my attention, there's always the [Github](https://github.com/vihanb/PPCG-SandboxViewer)

### Code

The code for this userscript is in the [Github](https://github.com/vihanb/PPCG-SandboxViewer) as `viewer.v2.user.js`.

### Todo

- (done) Auto-post to main.
- (done) Reply to comments from the Viewer
- (done) Make everything look better

Comment: Very interesting userscript code and also PPCG's sandbox idea, great food for thought! Not sure if you know, but linking directly to the [RAW version of the script](https://github.com/vihanb/PPCG-SandboxViewer/raw/master/viewer.v2.user.js) prompts the browser extension open its install dialog. Suggestion: use [this list of `@match`es](https://gist.github.com/BrockA/2476594) to pick all SE sites.

Comment: Will this ever expand to other sites like [Puzzling.SE]?

Comment: @Peanut does Puzzling have a sandbox? If so I'd by happy to add support for it

Comment: It used to but now it's kind of nonexistent

Comment: As noted by [HyperNeutrino](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8474/introducing-the-ppcg-sandbox-viewer#comment54753_8474), [Mr. Xcoder](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14075/74671) and [j-f1](https://github.com/vihanb/PPCG-SandboxViewer/issues/4), this no longer works because of the 'new top bar'. Do you have plans to fix this? or is the project dead now?